# Issue with sqlite in c

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

Today I've got a segmentation fault when I tried this:

```
int n=1;
sprintf(sql,"SELECT * FROM QUEST WHERE ID_Q= %d;",n);
printf("%s\n",sql);
rc=sqlite3_exec(db,sql,callback,0,&errmsg);
```

It doesn't even print sql.

But before I tried this it worked:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM QUEST;";
rc=sqlite3_exec(db,sql,callback,0,&errmsg);
```

If you have any idea what could be, please share.
Thanks in advance

Later edit: the whole code is here: https://github.com/byradu/database/blob/master/testing2.c

Comment: Probably an issue with `sql`. How is it declared and/or allocated?

Comment: @FredLarson better watch my whole code here: https://github.com/byradu/database/blob/master/testing2.c

Comment: No, post a [mcve] and include your error message.

Comment: You should be using [prepared statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) to get results from a query and safely bind user-supplied values to parameters in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't even print `sql`?

This is indicator that memory for sql has not been allocated properly. If you'd read documentation of [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) : *The buffer should be large enough to contain the resulting string*. Most likely, `sql` doesn't have enough memory to contain `"SELECT * FROM QUEST WHERE ID_Q= %d;"`

Please use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) for safer version.

> but before i tried this it worked:

This is because 'sql' is being initialized properly like this : `sql="SELECT * FROM QUEST"`

Update : Entire code has been added.

Before [this](https://github.com/byradu/database/blob/master/testing2.c#L57) line: Allocate memory for sql like this:

```
    sql = malloc(sizeof(char) * 40 ); // Your query is around 35-40 chars
```